# How to set different app name and toolbar title?

Tags: android

i want to set set different app name and toolbar title . Ex: App name in shortcut is "DM App" , and Title each toolbar activity is "DAMAI App", How to set it in XML ?

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.viewpagerindicator.IntroduceActivity"
            android:label="@string/detail_app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

my String

```
<string name="app_name">DM App</string>
<string name="detail_app_name">DAMAI App</string>
```

**where I want:**
Just shortcut name is DM App 
but Activiy Toolbar Title is DAMAI App

in my xml : Toolbar in IntroduceActivity still "DM App", but i want to "DAMAI App" .. how to fix it ?

Comment: in which string you have stored "DAMAI App" in strings.xml file? app_name or detail_app_name

Comment: please cek my edited question sir

Comment: I think you will have to set a custom view for your action bar if none of the answers below work.

Answer (score 0):

strings.xml

```
<string name="detail_app_name">DAMAI App</string>
```

Manifest file:

```
<application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/detail_app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.viewpagerindicator.IntroduceActivity"
                android:label="@string/detail_app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
```